# Access certain elements of a list

Tags: python

Can't figure out how to do this in a pretty way :

I have a list of n elements, 
I want to access every m elements of the list.

For example : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] and m = 2 would give
[2, 4]

I can do it simply with a loop, but ins't there a more "pythonic" way?

Thanks by advance !

EDIT :

Seems like I forgot something. 
I want, not only get those values but modify them. 
I tried slicing a[::2] = 3, but it doesn't work. . .

I'm searching for something similar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Slicing syntax does this for you:

```
>>> my_list = range(10)
>>> my_list
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> my_list[::2]
[0, 2, 4, 6, 8]
>>> my_list[1::2]
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
```

Here's a way to wrap a list to get the original assignment behavior you wanted, but I'm not sure I'd recommend it:

```
class AssignableSlice(list):
    def __setitem__(self, i, v):
        if isinstance(i, slice):
            for ii in xrange(*i.indices(len(self))):
                self[ii] = v
        else:
            super(AssignableSlice, self).__setitem__(i, v)

a = AssignableSlice(range(10))
print a
a[::2] = 3
print a
a[1::3] = 99
print a
```

produces:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 5, 3, 7, 3, 9]
[3, 99, 3, 3, 99, 5, 3, 99, 3, 9]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, which finally lead me to what I was searching for :)

Comment: Humm. Thanks for your class implementation, but wouldn't it be a bit overkilling compared to my solution below?

Comment: I said I wasn't sure I'd recommend it!  The class might be better if you're going to perform this operation in many places.  Your solution would require every one of those lines to get the `* len(x[::2])` right, as well as duplicating the slice on both sides of the assignment, which increases the opportunity for errors.

Answer (score 2):

Ned's answer shows how to use slices to access a portion of the list.  You can also assign to a slice, but you need to assign a list to the slice, for example:

```
>>> my_list = range(5)
>>> my_list
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> my_list[::2]
[0, 2, 4]
>>> my_list[::2] = [0, 0, 0]
>>> my_list
[0, 1, 0, 3, 0]
```

Note that when the step in your slice is anything besides the default of 1 the list that you assign needs to be the same length, however with a default step you can actually change the size of the list with slice assignment:

```
>>> my_list = range(5)
>>> my_list
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> my_list[:1]
[0]
>>> my_list[:1] = [4, 3, 2]   # replace the first item with 3 new items
>>> my_list
[4, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> my_list[2:5]
[2, 1, 2]
>>> my_list[2:5] = []         # remove the middle three items from the list
>>> my_list
[4, 3, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

I juste found a way to do what I want using slicing.

The following :

```
candidates[::2] = [1] * len(candidates[::2])
```

will replace every 2 elements of candidates by 1